# SimpleXMLElement::xpath (return nodes with *some* child nodes that meet a condition)

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu>
  <group Text="Group1">
    <item Text="Menu1" />
    <item Text="Menu2" Authenticated="0" />
    <item Text="Menu3" />
  </group>
  <group Text="Group2" Authenticated="1">
    <item Text="Menu4" />
    <item Text="Menu5" />
    <item Text="Menu6" />
  </group>
  <group Text="Group3" Authenticated="0">
    <item Text="Menu7" />
    <item Text="Menu8" />
    <item Text="Menu9" />
  </group>
</menu>
```

On the above xml I want to return all the group elements with their child nodes (item elements) but not those that have the attribute Authenticated equal to '0'

The result should be like this:

```
  <group Text="Group1">
    <item Text="Menu1" />
    <item Text="Menu3" />
  </group>
  <group Text="Group2" Authenticated="1">
    <item Text="Menu4" />
    <item Text="Menu5" />
    <item Text="Menu6" />
  </group>
```

*Edit: I have tried the following xpath

```
/menu/group[not(@Authenticated) or @Authenticated = '1'][item[not(@Authenticated) or @Authenticated = '1']]
```

but it returns the element

```
<item Text="Menu2" Authenticated="0" />
```

which I don't want in the result.

Comment: What have you tried? From the title, I suppose something related with `SimpleXMLElement::xpath`. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: I have added the xpath i tried and the item that is not desired in the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way with XPath to get exactly what you're looking for, but what if you just got the group of items that were authenticated like so:

```
/menu/group/item[@Authenticated!='0' or not(@Authenticated)]
```

And get back something like this?

```
<menu>
  <item Text="Menu1"/>
  <item Text="Menu3"/>
  <item Text="Menu4"/>
  <item Text="Menu5"/>
  <item Text="Menu6"/>
  <item Text="Menu7"/>
  <item Text="Menu8"/>
  <item Text="Menu9"/>
</menu>
```

**UPDATE:**

Ah, I think I understand what you're aiming at now. Try this:

```
/menu/group/item[(@Authenticated!='0' or not(@Authenticated)) and (../@Authenticated!='0' or not(../@Authenticated))]
```

and you should get:

```
<menu>
  <item Text="Menu1"/>
  <item Text="Menu3"/>
  <item Text="Menu4"/>
  <item Text="Menu5"/>
  <item Text="Menu6"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: This will return <group> elements that have the attribute "Authenticated" and is not equal to '0', however I want to return all the elements even if they don't contain the attribute.

Comment: I need the group elements in my result containing the item nodes, if that's not possible I'll probably go with a different approach than xpath, I thought I could accomplish this using xpath though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in pure XPath, at least not XPath 1. I would probably just clone the XML and run an XPath to remove  //*[@Authenticated=0], leaving you with your desired results but via a more roundabout method.